# Problem with Wayland

Tags: wayland, pkg-config

I had a problem with the wayland-protocol during the installataion of the Kitty terminal, the system didn´t find it, so I tried with `sudo apt install libwayland-bin`. I knew that this command install the wayland-scanner, but maybe it could help me with my original problem. During the installation, at the end of the process, I got

```
config.status: creating wayland-protocols.pc  
config.status: creating wayland-protocols-uninstalled.pc

Version         1.17  
Prefix          /usr

make: No se hace nada para 'all'.
```

So, it was creating the wayland-protocols. After that, I tried with `make` again, in the kitty directory, and I got

```
python3 setup.py  
CC: gcc (7,)  
Package wayland-scanner was not found in the pkg-config search path.  
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `wayland-scanner.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable  
No package 'wayland-scanner' found  
The package wayland-scanner was not found on your system  
Disabling building of wayland backend
```

I don´t know what to do and what´s the problem. Someone know how to proceed?

Comment: Try installing `libwayland-dev` , that has all the .pc files. Probably best to start over with fresh source when trying rebuild..

Comment: Great, thank you so much @doug ! I'll try that way. So, do you recommend to unmake what I did and try installing again after install `libwayland-dev`? In the afirmative case, is enough with remove the kitty directory?